# Add Text editor to my web application

Tags: asp.net

I need a text editor that I can add as a component to my ASP.net web application, but I need an extra feature in it, it's watermarking. Can you help me?

**Recommend components names**

[image: Text Watermark]

Comment: What do you mean by watermarking in a text editor?

Comment: Like watermarking in Microsoft word.

Answer (score 1):

Well you need to render HTML in this fashion

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="20" style="background-image:url('yourimage.jpg')"></textarea>
```

You could set the background-image style property on whatever control you use. I recommend the image should use a color scheme that will be easy to type over.

Answer (score 0):

A bit like @Shoban I'm sceptical about a watermark on a text editor, watermarks are usually added to images.

But you could use the url attribute of the background-image css style to the control containing the texteditor, for example:

```
.texteditor {
background-image:url('watermark.gif');
}
```